# MS Access: student movie db project - can't hire out movies

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to create a database for a movie hire company and I'm struggling with the checkout process. I have frmBorrow with frmBorrowStock embedded within to allow checkout/checkin of movies.

Whenever I try to add a new sale, I get the error: "You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table tblStock"

I've checked the tables and the relationship between tblItems(Barcode), tblStock(Barcode), tblBorrowStock(Barcode), and it all *looks* like it should (as far as I can tell). Is there something glaringly obvious I've missed?

I've uploaded a .zip of the database [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/49sw44otoh5bi9m/GHMH.zip?dl=0).

Comment: With related parent/child (one-to-many) tables, the corresponding form setup is main form/sub form. You might be trying to insert into the child table (via form with no sub form) and not setting the parent key. Please describe relationships and form.

Comment: Hi Parfait, thanks for the response. 

The table layout including relationships is here: http://imgur.com/3lrDZ9G

Form (frmBorrow), TransactionID is autonumber, MemberID is manually entered, as is CheckoutDate.
The sub-form (frmBorrowStock) links TransactionID from frmBorrow. Barcode is manually entered (which may be part of the issue, as Barcode on tblItems is "GH"0000000000). Check In Date is left empty (would be filled when the member returns the item), and Due Date is either 1 week or 1 day from today.

Much harder to explain it in words than it is with the image & db files!

Comment: From relationships, barcode is a dual primary key on tblBorrowStock and is related to tblStock. This means two restrictions: 1) it is a required field (cannot be left blank during save) and 2) you cannot add a new, non existent barcode. Did you do either of above two when encountering error?